# Converting Actionscript into HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript, port

Is it possible to Convert Actionscript into javascript and then deploy using HTML? If this is possible is this done?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into haxe.org
In addition look into the Jeash haxe library extension